# Meaning of "boroughs of New York City"

Tags: meaning, american-english

What does borough mean?
Does the word have a different meaning when used in *the five boroughs of New York City*?

Comment: I think that's the only meaning. "A borough is an administrative division in various countries. In principle, the term borough designates a self-governing township although, in practice, official use of the term varies widely." 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: I think this should be an answer, Bruno

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To me as a Londoner, a borough simply refers to a district with the larger city that has some degree of administrative independence. I believe the usage is fairly similar elsewhere, in New York for example.

Wiktionary gives the following definitions for [borough](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/borough):

> 1. (obsolete) A fortified town; a town or city.
> 2. A town having a municipal corporation and certain traditional rights.
> 3. An administrative district in some cities, e.g., London.
> 4. An administrative unit of a city which, under most circumstances according to state or national law, would be considered a larger or more powerful entity; most commonly used in American English to define the five counties that make up New York City.
> 5. Other similar administrative units in cities and states in various parts of the world.
> 6. A district in Alaska having powers similar to a county

The first definition, although not really in use any more, is perhaps the most interesting, in that it reflects the original meaning of the word in all Germanic languages - a fortified town/city. The word "borough" indeed derives from the Old English "burh", and is state to be "Cognate with Dutch burg, German Burg, Swedish borg, Persian bur."

Comment: Bradford, in Yorkshire, was until 1847 a town; in 1847 it was created a Borough, and then in 1897 a City. This is evidently meaning 2 above.

Answer (score 8):

In the US, a "borough" is a unit of government within a state. It's kind of like a town, but in the US, a town has a specific form of government that differs a bit from that of a borough, although the exact meaning differs from state to state.

In reference to New York City, a borough refers to a semi-autonomous government unit within the city. Prior to 1898, "New York City" basically referred only to what is now called Manhattan. Brooklyn was a separate city, Queens was a county composed of smaller villages, etc. These areas joined together to form what we now know as New York City in 1898. Each borough is basically a county unto itself.

Comment: Not "basically;" each borough of the city of New York is coextensive with a County.

Comment: This strikes me as a rather narrow answer... oh well.

Comment: @Noldorin: Not sure what you mean. The question specifically addresses the usage in "the five boroughs of New York".

Comment: The main question is the meaning of borough in general. Never mind, this has been accepted, I'm still liable to prefer mine though. :)